# Combining objects with duplicate key / value pairs

Tags: javascript

I have an object array with duplicate key / value pairs. I have used `.map()` to manipulate it's structure. I'd like to combine these duplicate pairs by adding the property `System.Title` as an additional object to the item that shares the same `Title`.

```js
var doctypes = [{
  "System": {
    "Title": "FIS NetImage"
  },
  "Title": "Notices",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "OmniView"
  },
  "Title": "Notices",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "Nautilus"
  },
  "Title": "Reports",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "FIS NetImage"
  },
  "Title": "Statements",
}]

var modDocTypes = doctypes.map(modDocType => ({
  Title: modDocType.Title,
  System: [{
    Title: modDocType.System.Title
  }]
}))

console.log(modDocTypes)

// DESIRED OUTCOME:
//[
//  {
//    "Title": "Notices",
//    "System": [
//      {
//        "Title": "FIS NetImage"
//      },
//      {
//        "Title": "OmniView"
//      }
//    ]
//  },
//  {
//    "Title": "Reports",
//    "System": [
//      {
//        "Title": "Nautilus"
//      }
//    ]
//  },
//  {
//    "Title": "Statements",
//    "System": [
//      {
//        "Title": "FIS NetImage"
//      }
//    ]
//  }
//]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the input array objects and output array objects are not one-to-one, you'll have to use `reduce` instead to combine the identical `Title`s:

```js
const input = [{
  "System": {
    "Title": "FIS NetImage"
  },
  "Title": "Notices",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "OmniView"
  },
  "Title": "Notices",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "Nautilus"
  },
  "Title": "Reports",
}, {
  "System": {
    "Title": "FIS NetImage"
  },
  "Title": "Statements",
}];
const output = input.reduce((a, { Title, System }) => {
  const foundTitleObj = a.find(obj => obj.Title === Title);
  if (foundTitleObj) {
    foundTitleObj.System.push(System);
    return a;
  }
  const newTitleObj = {
    Title,
    System: [ System ],
  };
  a.push(newTitleObj);
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```